# Firebug: "The 'charCode' property of a keyup event should not be used. The value is meaningless."

Tags: jquery

I'm building a calculator, and am using the following:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#Quantity').keyup(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Q1: Is keyup() the right event to be using?

Q2: Why is Firebug telling me "The 'charCode' property of a keyup event should not be used.  The value is meaningless"?  I noticed that it's doing the same thing as I type this question into Stackoverflow, so I must not be doing something too awfully wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears because jQuery uses its own `event` object instead of a native browser one, and in the process of creating this object reads every possible property of an event, including `charCode`:

```
props = [ ... "charCode" ... ]

for ( var i = this.props.length, prop; i; ) {
    prop = this.props[ --i ];
    event[ prop ] = originalEvent[ prop ];
}
```

Firefox rightly warns you that you don't want to read `charCode` in the case of keyup events, not realising that you're just copying it, not actually doing anything with it. Consequently any page you create with jQuery keyup/keydown handlers will spit endless warnings.

(IMO, jQuery should not bother copy this property. In the only case you actually want to use it—`keypress`—you can just use plain old `which`.)

Answer (score 4):

1) Yes, you are using the right event with `keyup`, so you get the latest value.

2) You can safely ignore this Firebug warning, it appears in many, *many* applications and is a result of [how jQuery normalizes the `.which` property for events](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L469), firebug should be a bit smarter about this IMO.

Comment: I would rather jQuery was a little smarter about this. It shouldn't be reading the `charCode` property of a `keyup` or `keydown` event. In any case, the `which` property is preferable for `keypress` events.

Answer (score 3):

This is not directly answering your question, but might provide useful information.

From [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html):

> keyCode and charCode
>
> The two properties are keyCode and charCode. Put (too) simply, keyCode says something about the actual keyboard key the user pressed, while charCode gives the ASCII value of the resulting character. These bits of information need not be the same; for instance, a lower case 'a' and an upper case 'A' have the same keyCode, because the user presses the same key, but a different charCode because the resulting character is different.
>
> Explorer and Opera do not support charCode. However, they give the character information in keyCode, but only onkeypress. Onkeydown and -up keyCode contains key information.

I can only assume that the `charCode` value is "meaningless" if a key is pressed that does not print a character (like arrow keys). Also, the `charCode` might be different from what you expect if the user uses a non-English keyboard. But I am not sure about this.

Comment: Not really. The point is that `charCode` is meaningless for `keyup` and `keydown` events, since only the `keypress` event contains information about the character typed (via `charCode`, or `which`). `charCode` in a `keypress` event works regardless of keyboard type; it's `keyCode` in `keydown` and `keyup` that will vary between keyboard types, so you've got it the wrong way round.