# What does this message mean in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [Firebug JS warning to jQuery 1.4.2 “The 'charCode' property of a keyup event should not be used. The value is meaningless.” To ignore it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996986/firebug-js-warning-to-jquery-1-4-2-the-charcode-property-of-a-keyup-event-shou)
> [Firebug: “The 'charCode' property of a keyup event should not be used.  The value is meaningless.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568106/firebug-the-charcode-property-of-a-keyup-event-should-not-be-used-the-value)

I have this error when I start typing on my textbox:

> The 'charCode' property of a keydown event should not be used. The value is meaningless.

What does it mean?

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                           
    $('#inputField').bind("blur focus keydown keypress keyup", function(){recount();});
    $('input.submitButton').attr('disabled','disabled');
    
    $('#tweetForm').submit(function(e){
    
        tweet();
        e.preventDefault();
    
    });
    
});
```

Comment: post any javascript you have that might be running. It sounds like you have subscribed to a keydown type event incorrectly.

Comment: Probably something to do with `recount()`

Comment: recount() is needed to count the number of charavters in the textbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by assigning jQuery to use a key down/up event. it's a meaningless warning and you can safely ignore it. You can turn off javascript warnings in firebug if you wish.

Comment: im using the google api, do they have the 1.4.2 version, sorry for the stupid question

Comment: I've edited the answer, as it still shows the warning if warnings are turned on in FB, anyway, do update, the 1.4.2 is shinier :) `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: why is  1.4.2 is shinier :))) thanks

Comment: you can see the list of changes here: http://blog.jquery.com/2010/02/19/jquery-142-released/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568106). it explains the problem clearly.

Comment: You could directly link to the original SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568106

Comment: I did in first post's comments. Hadn't noticed that the site is fetching its data from SO. link edited. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In non-IE browsers (before version 9), the event associated with a keydown (or keyup) event has a **keyCode** property, the same property IE uses for all key events.

only the **keypress** can return an event with a **charCode**. And, amusingly, a keypress can also return a keyCode in non-IE browsers, corresponding to the unmodified printable key or a control key.